# Package jetty is not available

Tags: pi-3, apt, packages

I try to install jetty on a new Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get install jetty
```

But i only get the following message:

> Package jetty is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'jetty' has no installation candidate

**How to install jetty?**

*(i tried update, upgrade, dist-upgrade and installed oracle-java7-jdk)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. apt-cache search jetty (to find the *package_name*)
2. apt-get install *package_name*

Comment: That was a quick one. Worked! I'm not used to linux/debian systems.